# PHP calling to a constant using text + variable

Tags: php, constants

I'm creating an application for my mother so she can play quizmaster. Since I have to play as on of the canditates, I cannot know the answers + questions.

My solution to this was, creating a constant page so she could fill those out without breaking my code. The display of my page would just be a question with a spoiler tag containing the answer.

Now comes my question, I'm not sure if this is possible, but how do I implement this? I thought about giving an ID to the page (through URL) so I can change the constants to Question_1, Question_2 etc. This way she can add as many questions as she want without me having to make more pages.

My page code would look like this:

```
$page = $_GET['id'];
```

```
            <div class="spoiler">

                <input type="button" onclick="showSpoiler(this);" value="Show/Hide" />

                <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
                    <?php echo ANSWER_1; ?>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Ofcourse, QUESTION . $page does not work. (use of undefined constant QUESTION). Is it possible to create the application in the way I just described?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I found the solution:

just use

```
$constant_name = 'QUESTION' . $page;
echo constant($constant_name);
```

Comment: You mean `constant('QUESTION' . $page)`. You want the *string* "QUESTION" here.